# How can I find the location of the css coding that is causing this button to turn blue when hovered?

Tags: css

I am using a website template, have gone through much of the style sheets and have used the f12 function in chrome. However, the button is ONLY blue when highlighted so I am really struggling to find it and turn it red. Is there a way to keep it blue so I can find it that way or should I look somewhere else?

["Purchase Now" is blue when highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb22s.png)

Comment: You can follow this- https://youtu.be/Bklz3lGTFi8

Answer (score 2):

You can try in the Chrome dev tools (F12) you can use "Force element state" to cause an element to behave as though it is hovered. When you have the button element selected, look for ":hov" in the "Styles" tab within the main "Elements" tab. That should let you toggle the :hover state. Hopefully that can let you see the button when it is blue to investigate some more!